# I am creating a VB.NET class library containing 2700 constants and their description. Would need help on what data structure to use

Tags: vb.net, class, dll, data-structures, constants

It will contain all the constants / error results used while dealing with unmanaged code functions. I have all the data at hand already.

The problem lies in how would I organize it.

I can easily write something along these lines:

```
''' <summary>
''' The operation completed successfully.
''' </summary>
Private Const ERROR_SUCCESS = &H0
```

and so on

However, I want to create a function which will give the description of the error that has occured.

Something along these lines

```
GetErrorDescription(ERROR_SUCCESS)
''' Returns: The operation completed successfully
```

Naturally this would require some sort of data structure to hold an array of values along these lines:

```
{0, ERROR_SUCCESS, The operation completed successfully},

{1, ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION, Incorrect Function}
```

Which structure do you all propose? Is their a better way to approach this problem. This will be a class library and so I don't think I can use a seperate database. This table has to be initialized at run time, when someone uses my class.

Just to give you the info,

Windows has 2700 Constants, each with its own description.

I know I can use the GetlastError as well, but this is a way to bypass that.

Example:

Lets say someone is using this function:

```
Imports MyClass 'which contains all error codes

Dim Error_Code as UInteger = MsiOpenProduct(ProdIndex, ProdCode)

If Error_Code = MyClass.ERROR_BAD_CONFIGURATION then
    msgbox("Error Occured")
    Exit Sub
End if
```

and in case someone wants a detailed error information then

```
msgbox(Myclass.GetErrorDescription(Error_Code))
' Will return: The configuration information is corrupt.
```

This is the functionality I want to implement. I already have all the codes + description in a database. Typing it is trivial as I can easily generate a VB class file using data from it. All I want to know is how do I organize it efficiently.

Comment: I am not sure about your exact question. If you want to reduce the number of constants (2700 sounds too many), you should provide much more information about what all this is about. If you want to know the best way to write 2700 variables I guess that it is up to you: you might set up a collection which might be accessed easily; a class; rely on external resources (file/DB/DLL, etc.);... it is a big size to write all this manually but a pretty small one for having memory-related problems (computers/VB.NET can deal with millions of things without any problem).

Comment: Clarified it just now.

Comment: You can create a custom class which will include as many properties as you want (for example: error code, error description, importance, etc.) and populate this class (a collection of it) at the start from a file, from a DB, from resources... or even hardcode everything. As said there are many options and I do think that the best way to learn is actually making mistakes: you should try something (without thinking too much about the objectively, best approach), just from the indications we have given you; and by bearing in mind that, usually, there is no objectively better option.

Comment: ... or you might even create a function which reads data from an external file directly (without storing anything in memory). Just try things, see the pros/cons of each alternative under the specific conditions and don't waste too much time in over-thinking everything before actually facing the real problems. PS: I understand that what Szymon meant was using a hardcoding you can make in your project (you have a Resources tab in your project's properties) which you can access at runtime: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6wkcc526.aspx Plently of options: just try things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
NameSpace ProjectName

    Friend Enum WinResultCode            ' probably as Long
      <Description("Success")>Success = 0
      <Description("File Not Found")>FileNotFound = &Hxxxxx
      <Description("Invalid Function")>InValidFunction = 1
      ' etc
    End Enum

    Class ResultCode

        Friend Shared Function GetErrorDescription(nErr As ReturnCode) As String
          Return GetDescription(nErr)
        End Class

    End Class
End NameSpace
```

The tedious part would be typing in the codes and descriptions.  The Code enum would be available to anything importing the namespace, so it could be used both as a translator and to define the return codes for projects or pieces which might be working with functions that use them:

```
 Declare Function SomeWinAPICall... As WinResultCode   

 nRet = SomeWinAPICall(...)
 If nRet = ReturnCode.Success Then...
```

You might be able to declare any API results as your Enum Type (which might need to be a Long) which may avoid having to use Ctype to convert the result to your Enum.  And, since the main function is Shared, you dont need to create an instance.

The `GetDescription` function is a fairly short generic routine that uses Reflection:

```
    Public Shared Function GetDescription(ByVal EnumConstant As [Enum]) As String
        Dim fi As FieldInfo = EnumConstant.GetType().GetField(EnumConstant.ToString())
        Dim attr() As DescriptionAttribute = _
            DirectCast( _
                fi.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(DescriptionAttribute), False), _
                DescriptionAttribute() )

        If attr.Length > 0 Then
            Return attr(0).Description
        Else
            Return EnumConstant.ToString()
        End If
    End Function
```

This is just a rough idea, some of the element scopes may need tweaking depending on the details.  But it would be one way to keep the name and description together as well as allow it to be modified easily.  At some point you may be able to place it into a DLL.

Comment: I never thought something like this is possible. This is new for me. I will definitely try this. Thanks BTW. Oh, and writing isn't the tedious part. This will be done in a jiffy. Once you have something tabularized, all you need is a formula.

Answer (score 1):

One way to write that kind of series of description for constants would be to use resource files. From what you describe, I understand the constants are some error codes and you give a description to each one of them. The resource file can act as a dictionary of your description and has a benefit of supporting multiple languages easily if you ever need that feature.

You can then create a function that will take a constant and return the error description. That function can take a culture in an overloaded method to return the description for the given culture.

Comment: I don't think that can work as a inheritable class while coding. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want the inheritable class for in this case. Can you please explain?

Comment: Oops sorry. Not inheritable. Just meant that you Import that class and you have all error codes at your disposal. Including the description functionality that I want.

Comment: Resources are embedded into the dll that the compiler creates so when you use a dll, all the resources are available.